# Yum hangs on setting up package sacks

Tags: linux, dns, yum, voip

I'm having trouble with Yum installing postfix. I'm using yum on a trixbox/freepbx system and trying to get voicemail-to-email setup for VOIP Cisco phones in an office environment. Anyways I try running the following commands but yum keeps hanging.

```
 yum install postfix --verbose --noplugins
 Config time: 0.083
 Yum version: 3.2.22
 Setting up package sacks
```

After that it just hangs for a long time and doesn't exit with an error code or anything. Could it still be trying to set up package sacks? How long does that process take?

I've already tried cleaning the database and rebuilding. I can't even use yum update without this issue occurring. I made sure its not my internet by pinging google for an nslookup and I got back IP addresses. How can I begin fixing this issue?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://vsingleton.blogspot.com.au/2009/06/fedora-11-yum-hangs-on-setting-up.html) see if it's related

Comment: Tried it but my configuration seems to be okay.

Comment: How many repositories do you have configured? What does `yum repolist` output? What do you get if you attach strace to the yum package when it is hung? (Alternatively run the yum command under strace to start with.)

Comment: Seems related (but behind paywall): *876853: How to fix Yum or rhn_check when it hangs at “Setting up Package Sacks”* -- https://access.redhat.com/solutions/876853